# How SQL LEFT JOINs with compositie join conditions work

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, outer-join

Suppose I want to select the rows holding the group-wise maximum of a column like described in this article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html . It does solve the problem. However I don't understand how the last solution works. If I do all the steps described, I get the desired result:

```
CREATE TABLE shop (
    article INT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL DEFAULT '0000' NOT NULL,
    dealer  CHAR(20)                 DEFAULT ''     NOT NULL,
    price   DOUBLE(16,2)             DEFAULT '0.00' NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(article, dealer));

INSERT INTO shop VALUES
(1,'A',3.45),(1,'B',3.99),(2,'A',10.99),(3,'B',1.45),
(3,'C',1.69),(3,'D',1.25),(4,'D',19.95);

SELECT s1.*
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price
WHERE s2.price IS NULL;

+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+
```

But I don't understand how this very result was obtained using `LEFT JOIN` and composite join condition. If I try the same query without `WHERE` clause, I get this:

```
SELECT *
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article AND s1.price < s2.price;

+---------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price | article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |    NULL | NULL   |  NULL |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |    NULL | NULL   |  NULL |
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |    NULL | NULL   |  NULL |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |    0003 | B      |  1.45 |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |    NULL | NULL   |  NULL |
+---------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Obviously, the first query just took the rows which have `NULL`s which happen to contain the values needed. What is less clear is how certain rows which do not satisfy the join condition get included in the result set and have `NULL`s in them while another rows are not included at all.
If I remove `s1.price < s2.price` condition the results look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM shop s1
LEFT JOIN shop s2 ON s1.article = s2.article;

+---------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
| article | dealer | price | article | dealer | price |
+---------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |    0001 | B      |  3.99 |
|    0002 | A      | 10.99 |    0002 | A      | 10.99 |
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |    0003 | B      |  1.45 |
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0003 | B      |  1.45 |    0003 | D      |  1.25 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |    0003 | B      |  1.45 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0003 | C      |  1.69 |    0003 | D      |  1.25 |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |    0003 | B      |  1.45 |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |    0003 | C      |  1.69 |
|    0003 | D      |  1.25 |    0003 | D      |  1.25 |
|    0004 | D      | 19.95 |    0004 | D      | 19.95 |
+---------+--------+-------+---------+--------+-------+
```

As far as I know, `INNER JOIN`s work this way: first a cross join is performed, then the results are filtered according to the join condition. For outer joins, I'm not sure. So I cannot understand why, for example, rows like

```
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
```

are not included at all in the result set of previous query (i.e. when `s1.price < s2.price` is added) while

```
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
```

get included with `NULL`s in their second halves. So could anybody explain the behaivior of SQL `JOIN`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using left join you always get all the rows from left table (s1 in your case).
When ON clause condition matches for particular row from s1 join result will include it as many times as match with s2 will happen
After that where condition applies to result set (if any)

You should also keep in mind, that conditional operators like =, > always return false if at least one of arguments is NULL

So row

```
|    0001 | A      |  3.45 |    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
```

not added because it not matches your clause s1.price < s2.price

as well as row

```
|    0001 | B      |  3.99 |    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
```

is added, only when you don't check prices like s1.price < s2.price, joining only using article.

Comment: Ok, so it turned out that the point was that each row from the left table would be included in the result set at least once and only then a lookup for matching row satisfying the condition from the right table will be performed. Thanks for getting the question and answering it!

Answer (score 0):

If the all the rows match between the two table there is not difference between left join  and inner join .. this is for you query without s1.price < s2.price

Left join is useful when the condition between the two table are based  on value that don't match .. then you have null value in the related field .. 
Using this  feature  a condition like   s1.price < s2.price (when  the row match for s1.article = s2.article) set to null the value   for s1.price when  this is smaller then all value of s2.article  .. then  is used for obtain the max.

For your question

```
    0001 | A      |  3.45 |    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
    0001 | B      |  3.99 |    0001 | A      |  3.45 |
                   ^^ s1.price is not <   of    ^^ s2.price
```

so do not meet the filter condition

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that a `JOIN` clause, no matter how complicated the actual term is, boils down to a simple boolean true (join the records) or false (no join possible).

That means that with your self join:

```
1/b/3.99 -> 1/a/3.45
```

will fail, because `3.99` is NOT smaller than 3.45. That leave no matching records on the "right" side of the join. But since you're doing a `LEFT` join, that's exactly what you get: all records on the left, with ANY matching records on the right - if there's no matching records on the right, you simply get `null` values for the "right" table fields.